# Converting iPhone app to a Universal app in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, universal-binary

I am trying to upgrade my existing iPhone app project to an Universal app but I can not find any option in Xcode 4 to do so. Where is it?

Comment: May I suggest that you accept Nick Lockwood's superior answer instead of Joshua Nozzi's?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

{ Outdated / incorrect information removed. Moderators, I've asked to at least unmark my answer as accepted. Please clean this up. }

**See Nick Lockwood's answer!**

Comment: even better (in Xcode 4 at least), just click on your app's target and then use the 'Devices' drag-down menu to choose Universal.

Comment: You helped me first by pointing this out before I found the simpler single-target method! So thank you.   =)

Comment: This is totally different in XCode 4.2, where could I find that?

Comment: @Nideo: I just checked this and it's *exactly* the same in 4.2 as in 4.1 and 4.0. Did you follow the directions precisely?

Comment: Hahaha, ooooops, I did not spot that Target, I went to the one down in "Products" folder. Sorry, and thanks!

Comment: :-) I *thought* you might've missed a step somewhere.

Comment: Down voting because of Nick Lockwoods answer. I hope he's right, but his is more in line with what I've seen online elsewhere. I'll know soon enough...

Comment: Joshua, since you seem to be aware yourself that the other answer is better, may I suggest that (since you can't delete this yourself) you flag and ask a mod to delete this for you? I believe that since this has more than 3 upvotes, you'll keep your rep, in case that matters to you. The trouble is that since this is accepted it's still the most visible answer on the page, and some people may not see Nick Lockwood's answer.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Just saw this. Flagged for moderator attention.

Answer (score 70):

**The accepted answer is wrong**. Creating a new target is how you create a separate iPad app from an iPhone app (i.e. a project that can be compiled into either an iPad or iPhone app), it is not how you convert an iPhone app to a single universal app that will run on iPhone or iPad.

All you actually need to do is switch the Device dropdown in the target summary tab from iPhone to Universal:

[image: Image showing above instructions]

Thanks to ObjectiveFlash for his comment which originally provided this solution.

Comment: That depends what you want to do. If you want to use the same storyboard and design your views to stretch for ipad, that should happen automatically as long as you use the autoresizing properties correctly in Interface Builder. If you want to use a different storyboard for iPad, just copy and paste your storyboard file and rename one of them <filename>~ipad.storyboard and the other <filename>~iphone.storyboard, then it will load the correct one for each device type (the same naming convention works with xibs, images, etc).

Comment: I have a 3 year old app that was originally targeted for iPhone. When I change the target device to Universal as shown above, the existing storyboards still do not display the adaptive layout options. How does one convert the storyboard after changing the target device to Universal?