# How to convert xcode 4.1 iPhone app in to ipad app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4, xcode4.2

- I was recently developed a big project on iPhone in **Xcode version 4.1.**
- Now i need to convert this app for iPad.
- I have verified so many links but all are regardig Xcode 3 ond it's extensions.
- How to upgrade, how to resize the view etc etc
  Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580935/converting-iphone-app-to-a-universal-app-in-xcode-4 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create two new projects, one for iPhone, and the other universal and see what differences are in place there, especially the app delegates.

Quite a lot of the things won't be needed, however the app initialisation need some consideration, and most views tend to happily scale up to ipad resolutions without much or any additional work.

That was how I added iPad support into one of my apps I was writing anyway.

Comment: But now i already did my application for iphone only.. it a long process to re implement the project for iPad / univeral

Comment: Yes I know, I had already released an iPhone ONLY app, and then by ADDED Universal support afterwards via the method described above.  You add the functionality into your existing project ultimately.  Using these other two NEW ones as a reference for the differences.

Comment: Your logic will be the same, so your model and controller classes won't need much/any changing. The only thing you'll change will be your UI - maybe add some iPad only functionality such as popovers to enhance the user experience on a larger screen.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how your app is build. If you are using Builder in XCode you can simply create new xib for each controller/view you have in app and name it with suffix ~ipad.

So if you for example have MyController.xib you will create MyController~ipad.xib and your controller will be loaded from this file automatically when run on iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the project preferences to universal gives you the possibility to specify a second MainWindow.xib in the info.plist file (Main Nib file base name (iPad)) which is the starting point for your iPad Interface. At this point running the app on an iphone would load your original interface and running on an iPad gives you the blank window once you created the corresponding blank MainWindow file.

Edit: You need also a second AppDelegate that holds the reference to your new window.