# Converting iPhone app to Universal app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

As my `iPhone` app is working perfectly on iPhone with full screen but when i try to  run the app in `iPad` it shows with  the iphone screen. Is it possible to run the app in full screen without jailbreaking the `iPad` or using the double pixel method ?

Comment: is this question anyway related to developers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580935/converting-iphone-app-to-a-universal-app-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to actually create one version for iPad, with the corresponding XIB's and classes and other functionalities you might want to add. Remember that an iPad version is more than justa bigger version of the iPhone one...

Comment: Well..in my app i  am already having two different versions of xib's for iPhone as well  as for iPad...since i choose the universal device while creating the project....

Comment: In build settings of the project  I change the target device family from iPhone to iPhone/iPad...still  not displaying in full screen

Answer (score 0):

This Question ask in earlier [But read this Official Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) This might be help flu for you..other option is Search in GOOGLE is best way for getting more ways for create Universal App.
Also [This site is related to Your Question.](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html)

Comment: you can also give vate for Duplication question rather then given Answer.

Comment: @NitinGohel this is for info... why i give downVote to OP he/she new at here :)

Comment: if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        
    {
        CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        [window setFrame:rect];
        
    }