# Convert application from iPhone-only to Universal

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5, xib

I've made an iPhone application in Xcode 5.1, but now I would like to run the same application on iPad.

How to I run it on iPad without compatibility mode?

Comment: You should create another .xib for iPad. Link to this .xib the same ViewController.
How it works you can see here: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-univeral-app-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Duplicate your iPhone-Storyboard and rename it MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard
2. Close Xcode and then open this file any text editor.
3. Search for targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"and change it to targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"
4. Change the code in the MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard from:

   to
5. Now save everything and reopen Xcode. The iPad-Storyboard has the same contents as the iPhone-file but everyting could be disarranged.

Hopefully this will help you

[Converting Storyboard from iPhone to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465769/converting-storyboard-from-iphone-to-ipad)
[Converting iPhone app to a Universal app in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580935/converting-iphone-app-to-a-universal-app-in-xcode-4)
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html